# What is the oldest time that can be represented in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a function `comp(time1, time2)` which will return `True` when `time1` is less than `time2`. I have a scenario where `time1` should always be less than `time2`. I need `time1` to have the least possible value (i.e. represent the earliest possible moment). How can I get this time?

Answer (score 181):

If using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module, [date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects), [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects), and [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects all have a `min` and `max` attribute.

```
>>> from datetime import date, time, datetime
>>> date.min
datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
>>> date.max
datetime.date(9999, 12, 31)
>>> time.min
datetime.time(0, 0)
>>> time.max
datetime.time(23, 59, 59, 999999)
>>> datetime.min
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.max
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```

Answer (score 17):

In python, the datetime object exports the following constants

```
datetime.MINYEAR
The smallest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MINYEAR is 1.

datetime.MAXYEAR
The largest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MAXYEAR is 9999.
```

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 4):

Certain functions in the `datetime` module obey `datetime.MINYEAR` and `datetime.MAXYEAR` and will raise a `ValueException` for dates outside that range.  These are assigned to 1 and 9999, respectively.

The `calender` module relies heavily on the `datetime` module, but in general, observes the [“proleptic Gregorian”](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#module-calendar), which extends indefinately in both directions.

the `time` module similarly places no particular restrictions on year elements in time tuple values, and calculates times and dates using only seconds since the epoch.

---

That being said, you cannot reliably process dates before about February 12, 1582, when the Gregorian calender was adopted.  Before that day, dates were computed using a variety of location dependent calenders, for which there is no support in standard python.

Comment: The final paragraph strikes me as a tad confused. 1582 is when the Gregorian calendar was *invented*. When it was *adopted* varies by country, and many did not adopt it until the 20th century. In 1583, you'll actually see calendars in Europe being *more* "location dependent" than in 1581, since a bunch of countries immediately adopted the Gregorian calendar while others remained on the Julian.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `time` module, you have no guarantee, because it defers to C library functions on the platform that can handle implementation-defined minimum and maximum times. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html states:

> Most of the functions defined in this module call platform C library functions with the same name. It may sometimes be helpful to consult the platform documentation, because the semantics of these functions varies among platforms.

and https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime states:

> The earliest date for which it can generate a time is platform-dependent.

That's because these functions take or return `time_t` values, and per the C11 standard:

> The range and precision of times representable in `clock_t` and `time_t` are
>   implementation-defined.

Unlike the `datetime` module, the `time` module does not expose any constants indicating the minimum and maximum values it supports, so if you truly need to find the min and max for your platform then you'd need to write some code to find them experimentally at runtime, e.g. using an [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search).