# Create a blank date in python

Tags: python, date

I want to add a blank column of date of format "%Y-%m-%d" to a dataframe. I tried `datetime.datetime.strptime('0000-00-00',"%Y-%m-%d")`

But I get an error `ValueError: time data '0000-00-00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`

How can I create a column of blank date of format "%Y-%m-%d"?

In R following works.

```
df$date =""
class(df$date) = "Date"
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: The arguments [must fit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) the following ranges: 1 <= year <= 9999, 1 <= month <= 12, 1 <= day <= number of days in the given month and year.

Comment: datetime in python are limited from `1677-09-21 00:12:44` to `2262-04-11 23:47:16`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with datetime module. The oldest you can go to is answered here:
[What is the oldest time that can be represented in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310740/what-is-the-oldest-time-that-can-be-represented-in-python)

```
datetime.MINYEAR

    The smallest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MINYEAR is 1.

datetime.MAXYEAR

    The largest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MAXYEAR is 9999.
```

source: [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.MINYEAR)

Comment: So, does that mean, we can not initiate a blank date in pyhton?

Comment: No. Since there's no month 0. It doesn't exist. Also, there's no month with date 0. And it's not only in python, this kind of date for format cannot exist in any langauge unless 0 corresponds to 1st month of the year or 1st day of the month, which is usually unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

```
initial_date = request.GET.get('data') or datetime.min  # datetime.min is 1

end_date = request.GET.get('data_f') or datetime.max  # datetime.max is 9999
```