# Error converting dbf to Pandas dataframe using simpledbf

Tags: python, pandas, dbf

I am attempting to convert a dbf file (from an ESRI shapefile) to pandas dataframe but receive this error:

> ValueError: year 0 is out of range

I am using the following code:

```py
from simpledbf import Dbf5

faunadbf = Dbf5('Listed Fauna1.dbf')

DFfauna = faunadbf.to_dataframe()
```

The error appears to be due to 0000 values in the STARTDATE and ENDDATE as it is OK if I delete them however I need to keep those records. How do I convert them so that Pandas will accept 0 date values?

[Fauna and Flora dbf files](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/EPPiTEls58)

Comment: See [pandas timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) which does not include year 0.

Comment: @Parfait: Does pandas handle `None` for a date field?

Comment: @EthanFurman, you can store  `NaN` in datetime fields.

Comment: Actually, there is no [year zero AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero)! There is year 1.

Comment: I attempted the code below and received this error    line 599, in _get_recs
    value = self._na
Attribute Error: 'Dbf5' object has no attribute '_na'

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the records from the dbf files with the `00000` date fields already set to `NaN` is to use the `dbf` library<sup>1</sup>:

```
table = dbf.Table(
        'Listed_Fauna.dbf',
        default_data_types={'D':(datetime.date, lambda: float('NaN'))
        )
table.open()
for rec in table:
    print(rec.record_id, rec.startdate, rec.enddate)
```

which produces:

```
(5595479, nan, nan)
(5595472, nan, nan)
(8581585, datetime.date(2016, 12, 12), datetime.date(2016, 12, 12))
....
(8906882, datetime.date(2017, 11, 22), nan)
....
```

Instead of printing the records in the loop above, you would add them to a `pd.Dataframe` instead.

I do not know if this method or @Parfait's<sup>2</sup> is more performant.

---

<sup>1</sup>Disclosure: I am the author of the `dbf` library.

<sup>2</sup>Thanks go to @Parfait for their help with acceptable date values in Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are facing two fundamental issues:

1. According to ISO 8601 (international standard for date and datetimes), [year 0000 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) actually equates to year 1 BC. However, Python's minimum `datetime` is January 1 at midnight in [year 1 AD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972447/1422451). So year 1 BC cannot be assigned.
2. Due to the [64-bit integer limitation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations). Pandas default dtype, `datetime64[ns]`, does not allow dates earlier than `'1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193'`.

   However, this second item can be rectified by using the [**`Period`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html) dtype.

   ```py
   import pandas as pd

   dates_df = pd.DataFrame({
       "DATE": [
           pd.Period(d, freq="S") for d in [
                "0001-01-01 12:00:00", 
                "1000-01-01 15:00:00", 
                "2000-01-01 18:00:00"
           ]
         ]
   })

   dates_df
   #                   DATE
   # 0     1-01-01 12:00:00
   # 1  1000-01-01 15:00:00
   # 2  2000-01-01 18:00:00

   dates_df.dtypes
   # STARTDATE    period[S]
   # dtype: object
   ```

---

Specifically for your use case, [source code](https://github.com/rnelsonchem/simpledbf/blob/8d9d07117aa673f08f3713917942d0bdd0587155/simpledbf/simpledbf.py#L282) `to_dataframe()` of `simpledbf` indicate a simple call to the constructor, `pandas.DataFrame()`, using dbf records and columns:

```py
def to_dataframe(self, chunksize=None, na='nan'):
    ...
    results = list(self._get_recs()) 
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=self.columns)
```

Therefore, consider retrieving the underlying data of `_get_recs` and convert dtype *before* `DataFrame()` call. Specifically, convert the generator to a list and then again to a dictionary via list/dict comprehension. Finally, convert to `Period` dtype for the `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE` values:

```py
from simpledbf import Dbf5 

fauna_dbf = Dbf5('Listed Fauna1.dbf')

# CONVERT GENERATOR TO LIST
fauna_recs = list(fauna_dbf._get_recs())
fauna_cols = fauna_dbf.columns

# CONVERT TO LIST OF DICTS WITH COLUMN NAMES AS KEYS
fauna_dict = [
    {col: vals} for col, vals in zip(fauna_cols, fauna_recs)
]

# CONVERT DATE VALS TO PERIOD DTYPES
fauna_dict["STARTDATE"] = [
    (pd.NaT if str(d).startswith("0000") else pd.Period(d, freq="D"))
    for d in fauna_dict["STARTDATE"]
]
fauna_dict["ENDDATE"] = [
    (pd.NaT if str(d).startswith("0000") else pd.Period(d, freq="D"))
    for d in fauna_dict["ENDDATE"]
]

# BIND RECORDS TO DATA FRAME
DFfauna = pd.DataFrame(fauna_dict)
```

<sup>**Note**: Above has not been tested.</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dates of `00000` represent no date and not the year 0001.

Comment: @EthanFurman, I clarify my point on the ISO standard and Python's limitation. But thinking now, my answer should nullify the year 0 dates from OP's data.